# Is presence of a benzene ring always a necessity for aromaticity?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

I just wanted to know: how is it we can determine whether a given organic substance is aromatic or not? (assuming that maybe their structures are given?)

Firstly, they need to be highly stable compounds.
Secondly, a benzene ring is a necessity... but I have noticed that there are several aromatic cyclic hydrocarbons which do not have a benzene ring, so how is this possible?

Comment: Hückel's rule can often predict if a planar ring will have aromatic properties or not. According to which, a ring having $(4n + 2) \pi$ (wherein n is a whole number) electrons is believed to be having aromatic properties.

Comment: [Aromaticity](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/A/A00442.html) is still not a very well understood concept and Hückel's rule(s) only apply to a tiny subset of aromatic compounds. (There are controversial viewpoints which physical features are necessary for aromaticity and there is still no consensus on how to measure it.)

Answer (score 1):

Many conjugated rings are known which have several properties in common, including an enhanced resonance stabilization and a diamagnetic (diatropic) interaction with a magnetic field passing through the ring. Benzene rings, or combinations of benzene rings, are the most common rings to exhibit these properties and were thus the first 'aromatic rings' to be recognized. But now we are aware of many such rings, some with as few as three atoms and others with dozens of atoms in the ring. I recommend doing a search for 'aromaticity' and reading up.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary that only presence of benzene ring can cause aromaticity. Any cylic compound which obeys the huckels rule for aromaticity i.e all the carbon lie in the same plane and their is 4n+2 $\pi $ electrons are present then the cyclic compound is aromatic. Presence of this cyclic compound can cause aroma.

Comment: Not all apparently conjugated rings obeying Huckel's rule are really conjugated.  Steric strain can foil the conjugation as in 10-annulene, or molecular-orbital interactions can lead to gaps in the conjugation as in sydnones  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydnone).   You can apply the Huckel rule to identify candidates, but when push comes to shove, proving conjugation is often nontrivial.

Answer (score 0):

The organic compound may be tested for:

1. Presence of a closed (cyclic) ring
2. Presence of a conjugated system: i.e. every atom must be having an orbital with 0,1,2 electrons in 'p' orbital [it would need to have a planar or nearly planar molecule; as could be tested by sp/sp2 hybridization of all participating atoms of the cycle.
3. The number of electrons in this conjugated system MUST be 4n+2; n=0,1,2,3... [Huckel's rule]

One could predict aromaticity in most of the compound using these 3 points

4. Sometimes, when we have more than 1 cycles, any possible closed cycle/system with the above 3 criteria would be aromatic
5. At times, we need to break the bonds, polar [like C=O] or even non-polar [like C=C] to consider aromaticity for the rings produced in such manner.
6. If a system is likely to be, aromatic by breaking the bonds as per point 5, it would be preferred due to higher thermodynamic stability of aromatic compounds

Hope it helps...

If required, I could post examples to elaborate each point.

Comment: Points 5 and 6 are overdone.  Systems with pendant $\pi $ bonds like cyclopropenone show some features in common with aromatic rings.  But with the conjugated electrons not fitting into a cycle they are really better described as "extended aromatic" species rather than aromatic _per se_.